# Setup a public server on my personal computer if port forwarding option is not available on the router

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver, home-server

I want to create a portable server with raspberry pi or etc in which I just have to enter the wifi credentials or connect physically to the router and it auto-maps the internal IP and the external IP. if I hit the respective External IP of the connected router the locally hosted site should appear.

Comment: You *need* port forwarding on the router for this.

Answer (score 0):

"Port-forwarding" is the only widespread mechanism that allows devices to receive connections through an IP address that belongs to the router. If it's not available, any other alternatives (such as proxying) are even less likely to be available.

You're probably looking for *automatic* port-forwarding, which your portable server can set up using one of two protocols: either UPnP IGD (more common) or NAT-PMP (less common). These are the same protocols used by various P2P/game/VoIP software. It's completely possible that a router doesn't have an option for manual port-forwarding but still accepts port mapping requests through UPnP IGD.

However, all such mechanisms only make sense if the router *has* an external IP address. But in increasingly many cases it does not – if CGNAT is used, the router *itself* can no longer receive any packets unless some kind of "port forwarding" is done higher up (i.e. from ISP CGNAT gateway to customer router), and ISPs practically never do that. There's nothing you can do to be able to accept connections at an IP address that's not yours.

Answer (score 0):

[Universal Plug and Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) (uPnP) has a mechanism to do this but it's often disabled as letting any application on a network open whatever port it wants to is often seen as bad from a security perspective, and you'll definitely not find this enabled on any public Wi-Fi network run by anyone who knows what they are doing.

You can set up a [Tor hidden service](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tor-hidden-services) on your portable server.  Someone else wanting to reach your server can then start up Tor and connect to your `.onion` address, as long as your server can make outgoing connections to Tor.  There won't be a reliable, secure way for someone to access `.onion` addresses without running Tor, but Tor browser bundles are available for most PC and phone platforms, and as long as your services are available through a browser they'll be accessible.